# HorizontalScrollView Inside an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am adding custom views to a custom ArrayAdapter. The xml layout I am using looks like this

```
 <LinearLayout>
     <HorizontalScrollView>
     <LinearLayout>
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
```

I then set the adapter for my `AlertDialog.Builder` as my custom `ArrayAdapter` and also supply the `OnClickListener`. My dialog shows fine and I am able to scroll the list vertically as well as scroll each view horizontally. However, when I click on any of the views it never fires the `OnClickListener`.

I have tried setting the top most `LinearLayouts` `descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` but that has no effect. Is there anyway to do this within the `AlertDialog`? I have tried even creating a custom Dialog that implements `OnGestureListener` but none of the gesture events ever get called either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm able to reproduce the same problem you're describing, though I can reproduce something similar.  Perhaps if you were to post a more complete and working code example, it could help to replicate your problem.

At any rate, the solution might be to not register the child components to have onClickListeners, because when they have onClickListeners, the parents then don't receive the click events.